# Can a galvanic electrochemical cell produce current only one time without a salt bridge?

Tags: electrochemistry

I think that galvanic cell produce current only one time without salt bridge. Potentional difference of both the electrodes are different and the electrons flow till their difference becomes same.Salt bridge is used to continue the reaction.
The cell can generate can generate current without salt bridge.Please help me to solve the problem.....

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will .. But it will stop in short period due to inbalance of charges in both beakers